# Changing the location of a node once the location is already set.(SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicscontact

I am working on a game that involves objects(fish) that move across the screen that you need to catch with another object(hook) that you can move up and down. Once the objects make contact the fish's position is supposed to become the same as the hook's. So in did begin contact (which does work, Im sure) I said, when the hook and fish touch make the fishes position become the same as the hooks.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let firstBody = contact.bodyA
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB




     if firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.fishHook && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.greenFish || firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.greenFish && secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.fishHook{

                CollisionWithfishHook(firstBody.node as! SKSprit

    eNode, greenFish: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

        }
    }

    func CollisionWithfishHook (fishHook: SKSpriteNode, greenFish: SKSpriteNode){

        greenFish.position = CGPointMake(fishHook.position.x, fishHook.position.y)

    }
```

For some reason when I run it and they make contact nothing happens. I know that did begin contact is working correctly because when I told it to remove the fish when it touches the hook it works. The problem is I am unable to change the location of the green fish. Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the greenfish is always the secondBody. this may not always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position of the fish in the `didBeginContact` method is only going to change the fish's position once - the moment the fish and hook touch. You need to continue updating the fish's position in the `update` method.

I would create a class variable in your `GameScene` class called `fishToUpdate` and when you 'hook' one, set `fishToUpdate = greenFish (or whatever was caught)` in your `didBeginContact` method. Then in the `update` method, update the fish's position by `fishToUpdate.position = fishHook.position`.

Comment: Are you talking about the override func update? If so what do need to do in it. I am confused. Should I say if the objects touched then change the position or what.